# How to make a if statement check if a image is set

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm using a plugin for Word press to set 2 featured images for post.
I need to make a if statement to check if the second featured image is set. 
If it is set it will display the code scenario 1. 
But if its not set, and if its not set then i need to display code scenario 2.

here is the function code i need to check, This displays the second image.

```
<?php kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'post' ); ?>
```

Comment: did you try it as simple as this: <?php if(kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'post' )): ?>...<?php endif;?>?

Comment: i don't think that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use kd_mfi_get_the_featured_image:

```
<?php if(class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages') && kd_mfi_get_the_featured_image('featured-image-2','post')): 
?>
<!-- If the image exists... Your code here, either HTML or PHP -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- If the image not exists... Your code here, either HTML or PHP -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/71/10223871/html/wp-content/themes/tshirthideout/single.php on line 27

Comment: @JohnFloyd can it be, that you paste HTML in there, or another open <?php?

Comment: yea  im trying to check to see if the image is set. if its not set then i need to display 2 different types of html code

Comment: @JohnFloyd I've updated the example. In the IF-Clause put the code you want to show in case the image exists. Below the ELSE you do your fallback.